# How to Open a Custom Spinner Item from MainActivity?

Tags: android, spinner

I have two activities viz., Activity A and B and I have a spinner in Activity B with 5 options(like country names). On clicking an item, a toast is shown to the user.

```
//Performing action onItemSelected  
@Override  
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),country[position] ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
```

In my Activity A, I use a button to open Activity B using Intent. The activity B is opened with the first item of the spinner.

**Question**

Is there a way so that on clicking the button in Activity A, second spinner item is opened and the respective toast is shown?

Comment: Are there more than one buttons?

Comment: yes there are more buttons in activity A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `setSelection(int item)` method of your spinner (see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int)).

For example:

```
//Activity B
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //find spinner
    spinner.setSelection(1)
}
```

Comment: And the param int item can be passed through intent ?

Comment: If the items in your spinner are hardcoded, then you only have to pass the position through the intent to activity B.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that you want to set 2nd item of the array as the default selection.

Use the following code:

```
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);        
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names));
     spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    spinner.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            spinner.setSelection(1);
        }
    });
```

I am late now I think...

Comment: No worries at all. I was late as I was implementing it in a new project.

Comment: As reported by many, using simply a line `spinner.setSelection(1);` doesn't work at all in every case and didn't work for many. Whereas runnable interface here is designed to provide a common protocol for objects that wish to execute code while they are active. This means that while the spinner you have becomes active during the transition of activities from 1 to 2, this method does its job and set selected item/position as the default instead of doing it after the activity of spinner. Simply, `spinner.setSelection(1);` is post processing whereas runnable does it at the very same time.